# Missing $ in bibtex while referencing

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.15 ...vard.edu/hub_feeds/1984/feed_items/207289}

?
```

Here are my references in BibTeX:

```
@online{
Mark10,
author = {Mark Easton},
title  = {What is {C}rime?},
date   = {2010-06-17},
url    = {http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/the reporters/markeaston/2010/06/what\_is\_crime.html},
Year={2010}}

@online{
Doha15,
author={UNODC},
title={13th {U}nited {N}ations {C}ongress on {C}rime {P}revention and {C}riminal {J}ustice},
date={2015-03-31},
url={http://www.un.org/en/events/crimecongress2015/pdf/Factsheet\_2\_The\_State\_of\_Crime\_EN.pdf},
Year={2015}}
```

BTW: I used package `url`.

Comment: it looks like most of the urls in your bibitems have underscores shown as `\_`, but in the item "Nor13", they're bare.  possible counter-argument: there is also a bare underscore in the url in "Und13", but that may appear later in the `.bbl` file generated by bibtex, so "Nor13" is what latex sees first.

Comment: as the error message shows, this works `/pdf/Factsheet\_2\_The\_State\_` because you escaped the `_` and this does not `rl={https://tagteam.harvard.edu/hub_feeds/`

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Since both of your bib entries contain a field named `url`, I will assume that you're using a reasonably modern bibliography style that recognizes this field. (This assumption rules out older bibliography styles such as `plain`, `unsrt`, `alpha`, and `apalike`.)

If you use a bibliography style such as `plainnat`, it is *not necessary* to "escape" underscore characters inside URL strings. Instead, be sure to load a package such as `url` or `hyperref`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@online{Mark10,
   author = {Mark Easton},
   title  = {What is {Crime?}},
   date   = {2010-06-17},
   url    = {http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/the reporters/markeaston/2010/06/what_is_crime.html},
   Year   = {2010},
}
@online{Doha15,
   author ={UNODC},
   title  ={{13th United Nations Congress on Crime Prevention and Criminal Justice}},
   date   ={2015-03-31},
   url    =  {http://www.un.org/en/events/crimecongress2015/pdf/Factsheet_2_The_State_of_Crime_EN.pdf},
   Year   = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```